# How to keep application working under screenlock?

Tags: windows-phone-7, detection, python-idle

I am writing a WP7 application which requires to play music even when screen lock is activated. I have done the following:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = 
                                                IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

and am also implementing the events as follows :

```
void RootFrame_Obscured(Object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
{
    _playunderLock = true;
}

void RootFrame_Unobscured(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _playunderLock = false;
}
```

But my music still stops when the lock button is explicitly pressed!

Am I missing something??
Also when music is playing the default lock screen does not get activated now, even though I haven't called

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = 
                                   IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Comment: Where/when are you setting ApplicationIdleDetectionMode? Once it's been disabled, it cannot be re-enabled until the next time the application starts.

Comment: yes, i know that. i was setting it in my App() class constructor( just to test out)....my problem is even when i disable ApplicationIdleDetection, my App is getting deactivated and the music;i am playing; is getting stopped, when i explicitly press the lock button.

Comment: Hi Vichitra, can you please write the code you written in obscure and unobscured events also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post may help: http://andreassaudemont.com/post/1068697622/useridledetectionmode-and-applicationidledetectionmode. If you need the application to keep running while the user isn't interacting with it (such as listening to backgorund music) then you need to disable user idle detection: `PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;` but from your description it sounds like you are having the problem when the user locks the screen, which is application idle detection. So, the only thing I can think is that you are setting it too early (sounds odd I know!). In RunKeeper we disable application idle detection(*) in the **InitializePhoneApplication** method in App.xaml.cs.

(*) **NOTE:** Disabling idle detection of any type is any action that requires permission from the user, so you'll need to add this into your application, too.

Comment: thanks for your time.
but i have already read that much in the Microsoft documentation of Idle Detection. my problem is that it is not happening as documented. Is it because of any changes in the Wp7, or my own mistakes in the programming of the events....
Further i wish to know other than 
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = 
IdleDetectionMode.Disabled; 
should i do anything else to keep my app from deactivating when screen locked?
is there anything to be done in the Obscured and Unobscured events?
thanks for your help!

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit more. Hope it helps.

Comment: it does thanks...
i have now changed my code a little
PhoneApplicationFrame rootframe = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
            if (rootframe != null)
            {
                rootframe.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(RootFrame_Obscured);
                rootframe.Unobscured += new EventHandler(RootFrame_Unobscured); 
            }
it is working but is unreliable.
maybe i'm calling it early...jst after the default InitializePhoneApplication(); in App()
Thanks again.